# How to chose selected values from an array of inputs

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have 7 input fields. However the user may only pick a maximum of 3 subjects. How would I be able to update these inputs into my table?

```
public function searchgrouppost(){

         $subject1 = Input::get('subject1');
         $subject2 = Input::get('subject2');
         $subject3 = Input::get('subject3');
         $subject4 = Input::get('subject4');
         $subject5 = Input::get('subject5');
         $subject6 = Input::get('subject6');
         $subject7 = Input::get('subject7');
```

My aim is to end up with something like this:

```
DB::table('mytable')->where('id', 6)
                    ->update(['subject' => $firstchosensubject,
                           'subjecttwo' => $secondchosensubject, 
                           'subjectthree' =>$thirdchosensubject]);
```

So far I have:

```
$subjects = [];
$inputs = Input::all();
array_walk($inputs, function ($v, $k) use (&$subjects) {
if(starts_with($k, 'subject')) {
    $subjects[$k] = $v;
}
});

$index = count($subjects);
```

Shown above I have all inputs in this `$subjects` variable. How do I extract these values for table input?

Comment: check them  all for the non empty ones

Answer (score 0):

you can always check if the val is not empty

```
$subjects = [];
$inputs = Input::all();
array_walk($inputs, function ($v, $k) use (&$subjects) {
if(!empty($v) && starts_with($k, 'subject')) {
    $subjects[$k] = $v;
}
});

$index = count($subjects);
```

By now you have only 3 val stored at array

```
DB::table('mytable')->where('id', 6)
                    ->update(['subject' => $subjects[0],
                           'subjecttwo' => $subjects[1], 
                           'subjectthree' =>$subjects[2]]);
```

Comment: validating 3 isn't my problem. It's knowing how to turn those three inputs into $firstchosensubject, $secondchosensubject and $thirdchosensubject

Comment: with this validation if(!empty($v) you filter only subject that was picked up, you've asked how to extract 3 from 7, so you filter by valid inputs

Comment: can you give me an example of what my update table code would look like? in other words how would i input those variables into my table?

Comment: I get an error message saying undefined offset is: 0

Comment: echo print_r($subjects, true); exit() to see of you have a values in an array

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest validating the inputs on the front end rather than trying to do with php. Here is some JQuery that would get you on your way

```
var numSubjects = 0;
$(".inputs").each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        numSubjects++;
    }
});

if(numSubjects > 3){
    // let the user know
}else{
    // submit the form
}
```

Comment: as well as- *never* trust client-side validation alone

Comment: If you made sure only three where submitted by the form then you could simply check the length of the array to ensure that you didn't have too many? I can see why you could want to maintain the flexibility in some situations tho

Comment: you client-side code telling me i can only submit 3 would not stop me submitting 4 or 37. client-side validation can always be subverted

Comment: @Dagon validating 3 isn't my problem. It's knowing how to turn those three inputs into `$firstchosensubject`,  `$secondchosensubject` and `$thirdchosensubject`.

Answer (score -1):

View:

```
<input name="subject[]" id="list" type="checkbox"  value="1">
```

Controller:

```
$topic = Input::get('subject');

foreach ($topic as $key =>$value ) {

DB::table('mytable')->where('id', $id)
                ->update(['subject' => $topic[0],
                       'subjecttwo' => $topic[1]]);
}
```